# How to fix 'NameError in SimplePages#index'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[NameError Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYWpg.png) I'm try to launch my ruby application using `rails server` . Prior to that I used `$ rails generate controller simple_pages index`. The error is generated saying NameError in SimplePages#index on http://localhost:3000/

Tried checking the index.html.erb and application.html.erb files along with routes.rb file under config folder

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'simple_pages#index'
  get  'index',    to: 'simple_pages#index'
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>R2</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul>
       <li><%= link_to "Home",root_path %></li>
       <li><%= link_to "About",simple_pages_about_path %></li>
       <li><%= link_to "Contact",simple_pages_contact_path %></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  <%= yield %>

  </<footer>
    &copy; 2018 Bike Berlin
  </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

application.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Simple Pages</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @simple_pages.each do |simple_page| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', simple_page %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_simple_page_path(simple_page) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', simple_page, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Simple Page', new_simple_page_path %>
```

The page should display no errors.

Stack trace as follows

```
app/views/simple_pages/index.html.erb:25:in _app_views_simple_pages_index_html_erb___2005229969295768109_70270503512740'
actionview (5.2.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:159:in 'block in render'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in 'instrument'
actionview (5.2.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:354:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (5.2.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `render'
actionview (5.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (5.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:44:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
actionview (5.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:43:in `instrument'
actionview (5.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
actionview (5.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (5.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (5.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:16:in `render'
actionview (5.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:44:in `render_template'
actionview (5.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:25:in `render'
actionview (5.2.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
actionview (5.2.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:84:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:142:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:14:in `block in ms'
/home/saishbhende24/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:14:in `ms'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:46:in `block in render'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:31:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:45:in `render'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:35:in `default_render'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `block in send_action'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `tap'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:194:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:256:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:134:in `process'
actionview (5.2.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:32:in `process'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:52:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:34:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:52:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `each'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:840:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:670:in `call'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:559:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:658:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:332:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:133:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: ur route file has name conflict

Comment: Please add the stack trace to your question.

Comment: @jvillian added the stack trace.

Comment: @Kick Buttowski what is the conflict with route file?

Comment: shouldn't the contents of your `application.html.erb` be for `index.html.erb` and vice versa?

Comment: Can you show the line of the stack trace, where it mentions the name error? Usually it gives you more info about what caused it.

Comment: @maxpleaner Added the image link mentioned line of stack trace

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace the following in routes.rb `get 'simple_pages/index'` wrong `get 'index', to: 'simple_pages#index'` should be like this

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a corresponding route/helper (from what we can see). You need to do this in your routes.rb

```
 resources :simple_pages
```

Comment: I tried adding that line. It is displaying undefined local variable or method `simple_pages_about_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007f1bb90a2ce8>:0x00007f1bb9085918>

Comment: @NB1962: yes, you need to add that route too (it's not among seven standard ones). Read [this guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/routing.html), it will clear much of the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

`rails g controller simple_pages`

# in your routes file

`root 'simple_page#index'
resources :simple_pages`

# in your controllers

`class SimplePageController < ApplicationController
   def index
   end
end`

Comment: It is saying Unable to autoload constant SimplePagesController, expected /mnt/c/saishrails/r2/app/controllers/simple_pages_controller.rb to define it